When I run the "npm run build" got the issue "TypeError: statsPresetToOptions is not a function" at Webpack's cli.js file
I am using web pack for a phaser 3 project and the version of web pack is like below,
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
"webpack": "^5.91.0", 
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2", 
"webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"

and when I run npm run build get the error "TypeError: statsPresetToOptions is not a function" at Webpack's cli.js file
refer the below image

tried upgrading webpack using
 npm install webpack@latest

and To address all issue, using
 npm audit fix -force   

but the problem did not solve.
